# Magento 2 checkout page getting shipping error

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, shipping-methods

I have used webshop matrix rate shipping method but after change to ship address getting error in my magento 2 store if anyone know idea please reply me

```
Carrier with such method not found: matrixrate_44989, matrixrate
```

Comment: You have an issue at  matrixrate,Please update the rules properly

Comment: In where update already in zipcode available  in our Tax Zones and Rates

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you please upgrade your magento version. Please check below url - https://github.com/webshopapps/module-matrixrate/issues/36